# What is the effect of lightning and thunder on the performance of your car?

Tags: engine, battery

After heavy thunderstorms and lighting, my car's automatic door locks wouldn't work. This is even if I push them manually (on the driver's side and the back side). After a few days, the door locks appear to work correctly. It's a mystery why they started working, but my windows roll up and down slowly on both sides of the front door. Despite having the maximum oil level, the engine doesn't start. It began making noises like "tok tok" and showed ENGINE LOCKED

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Check the voltage at the battery. If lower than 12vdc, you probably have an issue there. You can also try jump starting your car to see if the extra power boost will help.

Comment: It makes noises when I try to turn the key on the ignition if I jumpstart it. Will it damage it?(I worry about damaging it )

Comment: If you are jumping the vehicle correctly, there is no need to worry about damaging it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Well, The battery is dead and I recharged it.